# Bootstrap 4 navbar toggle not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I have searched this problem in multiple threads here on SO and it is a real head-scratcher as to why this isn't working. The below example (which is from a SO thread on this issue) works when it is in jsFiddler, but doesn't work when I serve it from my local machine.

So, I literally copy-pasted the code from jsFiddler to my own file and loaded that file in the same browser that rendered it correctly in the fiddler preview window.

I have tried adding the !doctype html tag and I have tried it with and without head tags around the title/link rel sections, with no change. The navbar is rendered with the brand name and globe on the left, then "link 1 link 2 link3", then a gap, then sign in/register/log out renders on the right side of the navbar. I have also tried serving this as a django page from the dev server and I have tried putting it in a flat HTML file and drag-dropping it from the filesystem. I have also tried several very similar examples from SO with the same basic result.

Here is the page on my server:
http://www.walesdata.com/test.html

Here is a screen shot of how it is rendering for me:
http://www.walesdata.com/Screen.png

I like the look and function of this when I see the working example, but I have not gotten it to work locally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>
  Site title
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Brand Name
      </a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
      </button>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link ">Link 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link ">Link 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link ">Sign In</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link ">Register</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link ">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-bottom text-center">
      <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed bottom</a>-->
      <h6 class="text-center">Footer</h6>
    </nav>
  </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

System info: Mint Linux and Mozilla Firefox. Served from django 2.0 and also from a flat HTML file on the file system.

Comment: The HTML you posted works fine: https://www.codeply.com/go/pm84HoGug6, and we can't help if the issue is not reproducible. Make sure you're properly including jquery.js, popper.js and bootstrap.js in that exact order.

Comment: What isn't working?? It doesn't loads the resources?? It loads the resources but it isn't displayed properly??

Comment: Here is a link to the page on a public server: http://www.walesdata.com/test.html and here is a link to a screen shot of it from my machine: http://www.walesdata.com/Screen.png

Comment: Edited the main comment to include these additional pieces of information.

Comment: I Checked your code it is working fine if you face any issue then include jquery in your html bottom.

Comment: Well dadgum, now I'm super weirded out, b/c I look at it on my phone and it works as expected, but as you can see from the screen shot, it doesn't on my laptop. I've also tried clearing my cache and Shift-Reloading, as well as loading to a different file name so I know it isn't caching anything, and still.. :S

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4.1, I fix this issue by manually invoking the JS to toggle with an `onclick` handler in a `button`:

```
    <button onclick="$('#navbar-main-collapse-1').toggleClass('collapse')" type="button">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bars"/>
    </button>
```

Example here: https://www.xn--javiercaon-09a.com/2018/01/servicio-atencion-cliente-social-crm-scrm.html

Answer (score 0):

The result of this was that the navbar-collapse will render as a regular navbar on a laptop, and then become the collapsed version on a smaller screen. So if you go into mobile view (Ctl+Shift+M in firefox) you'll see the collapse correctly.